# Python - scripting a “yes” response to all questions/prompts

Tags: python

I've come across a program run by `Python2`, which asks many questions of yes/no type.

I want to answer "yes" to all of them, but it's really difficult because there are literally hundreds of them (it's basically a parser of code, which asks about every found variable).

So, is there any possibility, how to force Python answer "yes" automatically?

I think about something similar to `apt-get -y install`. And I'm interested in answers about both `Python2` and `Python3`.

I'm using `Lubuntu 16.10` and my default Shell is `GNU bash, version 4.3.48`.

Comment: How about providing a default value of yes so you can just keep pressing Enter?

Comment: maybe you could redefine `input()` to return `yes` inconditionally.

Comment: there's also a "yes" command on unix which just prints infinite "yes" to standard input.

Comment: What OS and terminal are you using?

Comment: May I ask, why all the downvotes? I see, that the similar problem, was already asked, but I wasn't able to find it, as there is no mention of Python in the other question and I was asking about this specific feature of Python...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using [yes](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yes):

```
yes | python ./script.py
```

If you have a more complex state to manage during interaction, there is also [expect](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html).

`yes` emits `y` by default, but you can customize it by providing an argument (e.g. `yes yes`), thanks @tobias_k. If you need a portable way (in Python), go with the suggestion from Jean-François Fabre (or just hack the script).

Comment: YES WAS GOING TO SUGGEST THIS

Comment: Doesn't this only print "y" instead of "yes"? Maybe use `yes yes | ...`

Comment: doesn't exist on windows, though.